# How to send a random value in Node.js or express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, random

I had this express.js code. As shown below:

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const randomMonth = months[Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length)];

app.get('/v1/month', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ month: randomMonth })
});
```

But what happens is I always get the same response which is `{"month":"July"}`.

How do I make it send a random response?

Answer (score 1):

Because the month has been calculated upfront.

What you need to do is, having the same code called in the routing function.

```js
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];


app.get('/v1/month', (req, res) => {
    const randomMonth = months[Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length)];
    res.json({ month: randomMonth })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to generate random number

`const randomMonth = months[Math.floor(Math.random() * (months.length - 1)) + 1];`

Comment: Hey, that seems good, one problem is, how would i get a random word from the ones i have set, with what u have sent, it gives a random number.

Comment: months is an array here. so you can get it by index.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",  "December"];
    const randomMonth = months[Math.floor(Math.random() * (months.length - 1)) + 1];

 app.get('/v1/month', (req, res) => {
 res.json({ month: randomMonth })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `rando-js` instead: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rando-js

```js
const rando = require("rando-js")
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const randoMonth = rando.fromArray(months)
```